# Elasticsearch Java API in Java multithreading program

Tags: java, multithreading, elasticsearch

Im using Elasticsearch Java API in my program that implements multi-threading. Ive created all my indexes and necessary DB (CouchDB) with records.

```
GetResponse getResponse = elasticClient
            .prepareGet("elastestdb", "elastestdb", "id1" ).execute()
            .actionGet();

Map<String, Object> source = getResponse.getSource();
System.out.println(source);
```

The above code works when I call it directly from a function or with in function. However, if I place in Java Multi-threading run() method, it doesnt execute although thread is running.

```
public synchronized void run() {
    // System.out.println("Worker Thread started");

    while (!stopping) { //not stopped 

        if (!running) { //not running
            try {
                this.wait(); // wait until notify()

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("[Thread " + workerID + "] interrupted");
            }
        }
        else {  // Actual code start here
            if (!stopping) 
            {
                    System.out.println("Im running workerID " + workerID);

                    GetResponse getResponse = elasticClient
                         .prepareGet("elastestdb", "elastestdb", "id1" ).execute()
                         .actionGet();

                    Map<String, Object> source = getResponse.getSource();
                    System.out.println(source);

            } else {
                   //Do nothing  }

            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: what's the output that gets logged to the console? does your run() ever get entered?

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle yes. I get till this point "Im running workerID " + workerID, but its not executing the following GetReponse function also the run() method is a continuos loop (I keep getting  Im running workerID...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing GetResponse getResponse as reference from where I`m initiating the thread.

In my main class

```
 ThreadManager manager;
 GetResponse getResponse;

 manager.assingThread(getResponse);
```

In my thread class

```
  GetResponse getResponse;

  public synchronized void setRunning(GetResponse response) {
       this.getResponse = response;
  }

  public synchronized void run() {

       getResponse = elasticClient
            .prepareGet("elastestdb", "elastestdb", "id1" ).execute()
            .actionGet();

       System.out.println(source);
  }
```